# Symfony FormType filed EntityType from two separate Bundles gives error cannot convert to INT

Tags: symfony

I have interesting problem for forms in Symfony 3.2.14.

Have two bundles AppBundle and UserBundle.
In AppBundle have entity, with appropriate repository, and working formType.

If I create a form which has EntityType::class, field **and I'm in AppBundle - form works** (generated in controller on action etc.) but If I'm trying to use Entity located in AppBundle in formType created in UserBundle and creating a field in

```
    $builder ->add ('columnName', 
    EntityType::class, [ 
   'label' => 'Country',
    'class' => ProdCountry::class,
    'choice_value' => 'id',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'expanded' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
      ])]
```

**- when upgrading or inserting data - have error: AppBundle\Entity\EntityName.php - cannot be converted to INT**

in form type - datasource is entity in current UserBundle, and one of fields that I'm trying to fill is just an id from other entity (int in database)

yes, INT not STRING

Post data from form is correct and entity field passes number like 2, or 5 or any different id from db as it is configured in choice_value

and as I have said - EntityType field works fine if it is created in formType in same bundle as entity come from.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Class ProdCountry
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProdCountryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="prod_country")
 */
class ProdCountry
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", options={"comment":"nazwa kraju po polsku", "default":"NULL"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $polishCountryName;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $iso3166code;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $internetDomain;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $carCode;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $airplaneCode;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $phoneCode;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $orderField;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", options={"comment":"nazwa kraju w języku oryginalnym", "default":"NULL"})
     */
    private $nativeCountryName;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", options={"comment":"nazwa kraju w języku angielskim", "default":"NULL"})
     */
    private $englishCountryName;
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->id;
    }

    
    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPolishCountryName()
    {
        return $this->polishCountryName;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIso3166code()
    {
        return $this->iso3166code;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInternetDomain()
    {
        return $this->internetDomain;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCarCode()
    {
        return $this->carCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAirplaneCode()
    {
        return $this->airplaneCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPhoneCode()
    {
        return $this->phoneCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $polishCountryName
     */
    public function setPolishCountryName($polishCountryName)
    {
        $this->polishCountryName = $polishCountryName;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $iso3166code
     */
    public function setIso3166code($iso3166code)
    {
        $this->iso3166code = $iso3166code;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $internetDomain
     */
    public function setInternetDomain($internetDomain)
    {
        $this->internetDomain = $internetDomain;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $carCode
     */
    public function setCarCode($carCode)
    {
        $this->carCode = $carCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $airplaneCode
     */
    public function setAirplaneCode($airplaneCode)
    {
        $this->airplaneCode = $airplaneCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $phoneCode
     */
    public function setPhoneCode($phoneCode)
    {
        $this->phoneCode = $phoneCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOrderField()
    {
        return $this->orderField;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $orderField
     */
    public function setOrderField($orderField)
    {
        $this->orderField = $orderField;
    }
    

    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNativeCountryName()
    {
        return $this->nativeCountryName;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $nativeCountryName
     */
    public function setNativeCountryName($nativeCountryName)
    {
        $this->nativeCountryName = $nativeCountryName;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEnglishCountryName()
    {
        return $this->englishCountryName;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param mixed $englishCountryName
     */
    public function setEnglishCountryName($englishCountryName)
    {
        $this->englishCountryName = $englishCountryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide Entity  code ? (whole class)

Comment: @MichałG updated question for U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.

No Relation is defined in Entities User and Country

It depends on type of field in form - exactly - EntityType

```
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'userCountry',
                'class' => ProdCountry::class,
                'choice_value' => 'id', //not needed
                'choice_label' => 'yourEntityProdCountryAttribute',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
            ])
```

When both - Entity and FormType for that entity are in the same bundle - field in the database can be vchar or int and this will work fine.

When Entity is for example in AppBundle, but FormType is in OtherBundle processing the form will cause an error described above.

**Solution is to change field in Entity you writing data to as vchar**

or change EntityType field in form to ChoiceType

Answer (score 0):

Solution is just to give different names for forms in src/Forms/YourNameFormType.php

by setting

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'your_form_name_ver';
}
```

it will make any form unique

and then just ask for a proper form in the controler and  view